# Kids help family of aliens get to space

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I have been going crazy looking for it. I know a group of kids help a family of aliens hiding out on a windfarm to get home to outer space. I remember one of the aliens being pregnant. The aliens looked like larger E.T.s but I could not find a sequel. Help me if you know this movie!

Comment: Was my answer the right one?

Answer (score 4):

Nothing says "E.T. ripoff" like [Mac and Me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_and_Me)

> A Mysterious Alien Creature (MAC) trying to escape from NASA is
>   befriended by a wheelchair-bound boy.